# PayPal Standard Not Being Called

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

I have a CiviCRM test site running on 4.7.12 which requires the Gift Memberships extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/gift-memberships

I realise that Gift Memberships is only compatible up to 4.6 but it matches our requirement perfectly so I thought I would give it a go and see if it worked.

Everything appears to be working correctly apart from one major flaw, when using the contribution page containing the Gift Membership price set the browser isn't redirected to PayPal (PayPal Standard sandbox) and simply skips straight to the Thank You page.

I also notice that the contribution id is set to 0 in the civicrm_gift_memberships_codes table, consequently the email contains all codes rather than just the ones associated with the contribution.

I've only just got under the hood of Civi so I'm a bit out of my depth. Normal membership contributions are working correctly and, using Smarty debug, I can't see anything in the confirm form which looks significantly different.

I assume there is a change between 4.6 & 4.7 which this code isn't coping with so I'm wondering if anyone has had any success with Gift Membership under 4.7 or might be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying this in your local devbox or system - Is your instance accessible to outside world?

If No, then you need to test the same against a different server

Paypal standard needs a server open to outside world - I did the same test yesterday without any problem against Civicrm 4.7.12 - which worked alright

I guess this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. It is a local devbox but as I say PP Std works for normal membership, in as much as it redirects to PP, whereas Gift Membership makes no attempt to redirect and simply goes straight to the thank you page. 

Are you saying Gift membership works for you on 4.7.12? if so then it would point to a problem with my setup.

Comment: I am saying PP Std works alright in 4.7.12 - if you have issues with Gift membership then I guess payment function is missing in the extension

Comment: OK thanks @Ramesh

As the extension is certified for 4.6, I'm guessing that there is a change to the way payments are triggered between 4.6 & 4.7 - though that may be too simplistic :-/